# Как пишется Храм Всех Богов (вместо Пантеон)?

Tags: прописная-строчная, топонимика

> Пантео́н (лат. panthevm, др.-греч. πάνθειον — храм или место,
>   посвящённое всем богам, от др.-греч. πάντες — все и θεός — бог) —
>   «храм всех богов» в Риме.

Не кавычить же?

> Ближайший его сосед, а нередко и собутыльник – тот самый нагловатый
>   мужлан, что прописался **в портике храма всех Богов**, – при встрече с
>   нами всегда кричит: “Grappa barricata!”, потому мы его так и прозвали
>   – Граппа-Барриката.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В кавычках обычно пишут при прямом указании на перевод (переводится так-то). Если это словосочетание приводят как неформальное наименование Пантеона (мол читатель его и так слышал), то можно без кавычек, а капитализировать логично только первое слово, поскольку Пантеон пишут с заглавной, а языческих богов много ("Бог" капитализируется только в ситуации единобожия).

Answer (score 1):

Варианты встречаются разные: ***Храм всех богов, Храм Всех Богов, храм всех богов, "храм всех богов"*** и т.д.

Лучше остановиться на варианте **"Храм всех богов"**, **первая** буква названия прописная. Прописная буква для "богов" может означать только **высокий смысл, особую важность**, так как это не имя собственное.

Кавычки для обозначения этого названия вряд ли уместны. Здесь нет условности, необычного значения, это просто еще одно название, кроме Пантеона.

Вариант "храм всех Богов" смотрится **как авторский,** к нему могут быть вопросы.

Пример: Расположенный в Риме **Храм всех богов** (или, как называется сейчас это сооружение, Пантеон) на момент своего возведения был посвящен главным богам, почитавшимся в Римской империи. http://fb.ru/article/320166/hram-vseh-bogov-v-rime-nazvanie-foto-opisanie